# checking symbol equality in defmacro (clojure)

Tags: clojure, macros, symbols

This returns `false`.

```
(defmacro scratch [pattern]
  `(= 'b (first ~pattern)))

(scratch '(b))
```

However, the output of the following is `b`.

```
(defmacro scratch2 [pattern]
  `(first ~pattern))

(scratch2 '(b))
```

How do I setup the first macro to return `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is happening, because the 'b that you introduce in macro is namespaced:

example:

```
user> (defmacro nsmac []
        `(namespace 'b))

user> (nsmac)
;;=> "user"
```

while the value you pass isn't:

```
user> (namespace (first '(b)))
;;=> nil
```

so, you can pass the namespaced symbol to a macro, like this:

```
user> (scratch '(user/b)) 
;;=> true
```

or you can fix you macro to use unnamespaced symbol (known trick with qoute-unquote):

```
(defmacro scratch [pattern]
  `(= '~'b (first ~pattern)))

user> (scratch '(b)) 
;;=> true
```

but what you really want, is to check this one in compile-time, because this macro you have is better as a plain function, since it doesn't employ any macro-related goodness.

It could look like this:

```
(defmacro scratch [pattern]
  (= 'b (first pattern)))

(scratch (b))
;;=> true
```

something about namespacing can be found [in this article](https://8thlight.com/blog/aaron-lahey/2016/07/20/relationship-between-clojure-functions-symbols-vars-namespaces.html)

Comment: So my clojure REPL prints namespaced symbols without their namespaces when in defmacro. Otherwise it prints namespace too. Using `macroexpand`is helpful as it does what I intend